# Dpdk-testpmd panic "mlx5_net: Cannot register matcher" in DPDK 23.03

Tags: centos, intel, dpdk, mellanox

When I running dpdk-testpmd in DPDK 23.03, it reports the error:
[image]

However, I have not faced the same error when I running dpdk-testpmd in DPDK 20.05. Why does this error occur? How should I fix it?